# Html5 table in MVC3 framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

Sorry for asking this vague question. Any link will be appreciated even. I would like to use HTML 5 table using MVC3 framework. Any clue is good here. Please help...

Kind regards,
Suresh

Comment: Have you any experience using an HTML `<table>`? There's not really any special treatment of it for HTML5 or ASP.NET MVC3.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure you have the MVC 3 tools update

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/03/asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx